# Integer-sided isosceles triangle with area equal to $120$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, area

BdMO National 2013 Junior Q. 2:

> Two isosceles triangles are possible with 120 square unit area of each and length of edges are integers. Such one is  with 17, 17 and 16 unit edges. Determine the length of edges of second one. [Hint: In $ \bigtriangleup ABC $ if $ AB = AC $ and $ AD $ is perpendicular to $ BC $ then $  BD = CD $ .]

Please help me, or just give me a hint to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the solution you have, cut it along the axis of symmetry and rearrange to another isosceles triangle.

Comment: Can you just explain it a little more?

Comment: Sketch $\triangle ABC$.  As mentioned in the hint, the altitude $AD$ bisects the triangle into equal halves, in fact with integer sides.  Rearrange these two pieces. Better to draw and figure out, verbal description is perhaps more complex than drawing.

Comment: Thanks. I think I've found the answer right now. I think the base would be 15 and the other edges would be 17. Is it correct? By the way, thanks.

Comment: I should improve my geometry. I'm so bad at it! Can you suggest some website for improving my geometry skills?

Comment: You may want to check https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Olympiad_books#Geometry

Comment: @RuhanHabib Solving more and more problems is the only cure for it.  You would be introduced to new tricks, concepts and theorems, and you will learn use them only if you start solving problems [and by  reading good books and websites] .

Comment: Base should be $30$...

Answer (score 1):

Cut the triangle along the axis of symmetry and rotate it to get another one.
[image]
So, the answer is $30,17,17$.